# How to convert string to number in gnuplot

Tags: linux, unix, gnuplot

Is there a way to convert strings representing numbers (in scientific format) to numbers in gnuplot. I.e.

```
stringnumber="1.0e0"
number=myconvert(stringnumber)

plot [-1:1] number
```

I search myconvert possibly using shell commands.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can add 0 to the string:

```
stringnumber="1.0e0"
number=stringnumber + 0
plot [-1:1] number
```