# Gnuplot: store last data point as variable

Tags: gnuplot

I was wondering if there is an easy way, using Gnuplot, to get the last point in a data file say data.txt and store the values in a variable.

From this question, 
[accessing the nth datapoint in a datafile using gnuplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13986596/accessing-the-nth-datapoint-in-a-datafile-using-gnuplot)
I know that I can get the X-Value using stats and GP_VAL_DATA_X_MAX variable, but is there a simple trick to get the corresponding y-value?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use Gnuplot, you can

```
plot 'data.txt'
plot[GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX:] 'data.txt'
show variable GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX
```

OR

```
plot 'data.txt'
plot[GPVAL_DATA_X_MAX:] 'data.txt'
print GPVAL_DATA_Y_MAX
```

Answer (score 5):

A third possibility is to write each ordinate value into the same user variable during plotting. Last value stays in:

```
 plot dataf using 1:(lasty=$2)
 print lasty
```

Comment: You mean `using 1:(latsy=$2)` ?

Answer (score 3):

If you know how your file is organised (separators, trailing empty lines) and you have access to standard Unix tools, you make use of Gnuplot’s `system` command. For example, if you have no trailing newlines and your values are separated by tabs, you can do the following:

```
x = system("tail -n 1 data.txt | cut -f 1")
y = system("tail -n 1 data.txt | cut -f 2")
```

(`tail` gets the last `n` lines of a file. `cut` extracts the column `f`.)

Note that `x` and `y` are strings if obtained this way, but for most applications this should not matter. If you must convert them, [you can still add zero](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9739315/2127008).

Comment: This answer also works with any delimiter, for example cut -d ' ' 1

Answer (score 1):

Let me add a 4th solution, because:

- To be very precise, the OP asked about the **last** x-value and the correscponding y-value.
  @TomSolid's solution will return the **maximum** x-value and its corresponding y-value.
  However, strictly speaking the maximum value might not necessarily be the last value, unless the x-data is sorted in ascending order.
  The result for the example below would be `10` and `14` instead of `8` and `18`.
- @Karl's solution will return the last y-value *and* as well plots something, although you maybe just want to extract the value and plot something else. Ideally, you could combine extraction and plotting.
- @Wrzlprmft's solution is using the Linux function `tail` which is not platform-independent (for Windows you first would have to install such utilities)

Hence, here is a solution:

- platform-independent and gnuplot-only
- returns the last x-value and corresponding y-value
- doesn't create any dummy plot

**Script:**

```
### get the last x-value and corresponding y-value
reset session

$Data <<EOD
1     11
2     12
3     13
10    14
5     15
6     16
7     17
8     18
EOD

stats $Data u (lastX=$1,lastY=$2) nooutput
print lastX, lastY
### end of script
```

**Result:**

```
8.0   18.0
```