# Is there a way to add the last value of the data column to a legend

Tags: gnuplot

I want to add the last value of a series to the plots legend. I tried different variants of this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37285338/1298461) answer like so:

```
plot filename using 1:2:(last=$2) title sprintf("1/N %0.2f", last) with lines
```

But this puts `nan` into the label. And if I do `1:(last=$2)` this messes up the whole line.

The problem is I need to make it platform independent meaning it needs to run on windows and linux. So I can not just tail and awk. Is there a build in way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use anything from the `using` statement in the plot's title. You can process your data first with `stats` and `using (last=$2)` and use that result in the plot:

```
stats filename using (last=$2) nooutput
plot filename using 1:2 title sprintf("1/N %0.2f", last) with lines
```